# Can`t get response from RxJava in Unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito, rx-java, rx-java2

I tried to get response from RxJava2 in Unit test, I found an example how to do it, but  i can`t see and response, can yoy help me?  Thank you.
The code itself has been working for a long time, without problems, and when the tests were required I encountered a problem, similar examples are more or less the same, but everywhere it is done this way, but it does not work for me.

There my code from presenter:

```
  fun register(
    email: String,
    password: String,
    termsEnabled: Boolean,
    dayOfBirth: Int,
    monthOfBirth: Int,
    yearOfBirth: Int,
    formattedBirthDate: String,
    state: String?
) {
    addDisposable(
        registerUseCase.run(
            RegisterUseCase.RegisterRequest(
                email,
                password,
                termsEnabled,
                formattedBirthDate,
                state ?: ""
            )
        )
            .observeOn(mainThreadScheduler)
            .subscribeOn(backgroundScheduler)
            .subscribe(
                { 
                  getView?.showEmptyPassword()
                }, {
                 getView?.showEmptyPassword()
                    }
            )
    )
}
```

And test:

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { 
    Schedulers.trampoline() }
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

    
    presenter = CreateAccountPresenter(
        mainThreadScheduler,
        backgroundScheduler,
        registerUseCase,
        getUserDataUseCase,
        getStatesUseCase,
        regexUtils,
        router,
        resourceUtils,
        deviceSharedPreferences
    )
    presenter.setView(view)
}


@Test
fun testRegister() {

    given(registerUseCase.run(RegisterUseCase.RegisterRequest(
        EMAIL, PASSWORD, true,
                FORMATTED_BIRTHDAY, STATE))
    ).willReturn(Single.just(RegisterResponse(false, "ok", "id")))

    presenter.register(
        EMAIL,
        PASSWORD,
        true,
        1,
        1,
        1,
        FORMATTED_BIRTHDAY,
        STATE)

    verify(view).showEmptyPassword()
}
```

But issue is:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
view.showEmptyPassword();
-> at 
com.unikrn.esports.umode.CreateAccountPresenterTest.testRegister(CreateAccountPresenterTest.kt:179)
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Comment: Can you include the code for the creation of the presenter for the tests? My bet is that you're running everything in a background threat. While it works for the app, it won't for a test (that needs to be blocking)

Comment: Yeah, i tried to set delay in code and in test, nothing help

Comment: @Pelocho I think you right, but how to fix it?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're doing some computation in a background thread and, even being mocked, it doesn't have enough time to finish before the `verify` invocation

Since you're already injecting the schedulers for your operations, specify that both of them are `trampoline` so everything runs in the same thread

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    presenter = CreateAccountPresenter(
        Schedulers.trampoline(),
        Schedulers.trampoline(),
        ...
    )
}
```

Worst case scenario, you can add some blocker element (such as a `Semaphore`) that blocks the test execution and you release it in one of your `view` methods (that you'll need to stub)

As per the docs, [Schedulers.trampoline()](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/schedulers/Schedulers.html#trampoline--) schedules all tasks in the current thread so everything will be blocking. In case you want to directly use some schedulers like `Schedulers.io()` you'll need to override them in a similar way you're doing now with

```
RxAndroidPlugins.setInitMainThreadSchedulerHandler { Schedulers.trampoline() } // Override MainThreadScheduler
```

Note that the previous snippet is just an example and you'll need to adapt it

Comment: Yeah, it works, thank you, but can you explain why? What do Schedulers.trampoline() ?

Comment: And if i will use just 
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
It will not work? And why?

Comment: Since you were already using it in your code I assumed that you knew what was and how it worked. I'll add some explanation in the answer

Comment: It created an old developer of that project, i can use it, but i don`t know why he did it, that why i answered

Comment: I recommend you taking a look to the official documentation in http://reactivex.io/. Otherwise you'll face several issues than can be easily avoided by not making some silly mistakes

Comment: did you mean that https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava ?